# simple regular expression in XML

Tags: xml, regex

I am trying to move a number of files using Mule from one directory to another.
File names are like ABC_123.xml, ABC_456.xml etc. the pattern being ABC_whatever.xml.
I thought

```
<file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(^ABC).xml" caseSensitive="true"/>
```

would do the job. But it does not seem to be working. Where should I even look for documentation?
any help?

Following is the configuration xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <flow name="basicTut1" doc:name="basicTut1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/Input" moveToDirectory="/home/Output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(^ABC).xml" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be fixed

```
^ABC.*\.xml$
```